# How can I access outbound emails with Java code

Tags: outbound-email, audience-manager

I need to access the email pages and replace placeholders with some custom values fetched from another database. I will also need access to the mailing list. I plan to write a web service to do so. The part I am not sure of is how to replace the page template placeholders with custom values in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs on the Content Manager side are .NET only. Although there is an Audience Manager Web service, it currently only exposes functionality relevant to importing and exporting Contacts and Keywords.

My suggestion would be to write this tool in .NET instead of trying to use Java for it.